# Check data entered against a database

Tags: html, mysql, jstl

I'm trying to get input from a webpage and query a database and if the input matches the database then move to the next page and be "logged in"

```
<sql:query var="result">
SELECT * from Customer where customer_number=1;
</sql:query>
<form>
Enter your surname<input type="text" name="surname"/><br><br>
Enter your passphrase <input type="text" name="passphrase"/>
<input type="submit" name="B1" value="Submit" />
</form>
<c:if surname="${result.rows[0]['surname']}">
<p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
```

At the moment it gets one line of the database but I need it search the database for one parameter and then if that exists then check that tuple for the other. At the moment with this I get an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - /withdraw_basic.jsp (line: 23, column: 0) According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute test is mandatory for tag if
```

and I don't know why this is failing.
I'm new to this so be gentle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have this at the top of your document:

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
```

Also you forgot to close your `p` tag properly:

```
<p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
<!-- Missed a slash here                   ^ -->
```

I wanted to comment this but didn't have 50 reps!